# card layout implementation

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, math, layout

im looking for an implementation of a card layout:

- given a fixed width canvas, an arbitrary number of rectangles will be laid out, with some margins initially. fixed Y coordinate.
- if the number of rectangles doesnt fit the canvas width, each rectangle will be partly overlayed by the next one. the last reactangle showing its whole width
- wanted to have the layout auto adjust as I add a new rectangle

if there is such thing exist already or similar, pls share. was hoping i dont have to write it.

Comment: This doesn't seem horribly difficult to write. Then again I don't know if there's a library or sample code somewhere that already does this, so if there is that would obviously be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @puggsoy, I can't think of a library that does this, but here's a simple function that should do what you need.

```
function updateLayout(canvasWidth:Number, rects:Array, rectWidth:Number, margin:Number):void
{
    var totalWidth:Number = rects.length * rectWidth + ((rects.length-1)*margin);
    var offset:Number = rectWidth + margin;
    if(totalWidth > canvasWidth)
    {
        offset = (canvasWidth - rectWidth) / (rects.length-1);
    }

    var currX:Number = 0;
    for each(var rect:DisplayObject in rects)
    {
        rect.x = currX;
        currX += offset;
    }
}
```

This assumes that the DisplayObjects in the rects array are ordered by their childIndex.